# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 ()

Tags: wp-admin, admin, errors

This error appeared only yesterday. When I try to do anything in admin except adding posts/pages, there is a white screen and chrome console reveals. I can't update wordpress core, can't update/install/delete plugins ...

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 ()
```

No idea what's the issue and how to fix it. Thanks for helping out!

UPDATE - this was a Chrome issue - after I cleared my cookies, everything works OK

Could somebody explain it to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is explanation of the 431 error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431